# Does Xcode support any form of asset scaling one image to all asset sizes?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, assets, scaling

One thing I find **very** annoying with Xcode and iOS application projects is that assets (such as *AppIcon* or *LaunchImage*) seem to require certain images of different sizes, so what I usually end up doing is spending a ton of time to scale a larger image down to these required sizes. Is there any way to do this automatically in Xcode, for it to take one image (a large PNG or even a vector image) and scale it to all of these sizes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this by using PDFs. Starting with Xcode 6 PDFs are supported as assets. You just have to put one PDF with the base size and all the other sizes are generated from it at compile time. Note that the app still uses PNGs at runtime. [Here](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/) is a nice tutorial about PDFs.

However at the time of this writing *AppIcon* and *LaunchImage* resources do not support this feature as you noticed. For those you could use some plugin that generates those sizes automatically in the designing app you use (there re such plugins for the most popular applications like Ilustrator or Photoshop). This is not ideal but it does speed up the process.

Comment: Wow, thank you a million times! Although, I think you should add the relevant bits to your answer in case the site ever goes down.

Comment: It seems I accepted the answer too soon...while this works for regular images, there does not seem to be any support for vectors in *AppIcon* or *LaunchImage* assets, is there? For regular image assets, indeed this does seem to work. For example, if you right click your assets and add a *New iOS App Icon* asset type, you cannot change its type to a vector type of asset.

Comment: Well, you are right this does not work with Appicon and LaunchImage. I'll edit my answer.